# Python: np.vectorize to return "float"

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, floating, piecewise

Running the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def xon (ton, t):
    if ton <= t:
        return (t-ton)/5
    else:
        return 0

vxon = np.vectorize(xon)
t = np.linspace(0, 49, 50)    
xontest = vxon(0, t)
plt.plot(t, xontest, '-')
plt.show()
```

I get the plot:
[image]

But when I try to plot for values of ton, wchich are different than zero, e.g.:

```
xontest = vxon(2, t)
```

the plot seems to round all the xon values to integer:

[image]

What in my code causes such behaviour?

Comment: If you are using Python2, perhaps changing `return (t-ton)/5` to `return (t-ton)/5.0` would fix it.

Comment: Sorry, looked at the wrong number. It is 2.7.9.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, because it was completely off-track. While `5` is an integer, `t` isn't an integer in your case. Rather, it's a NumPy array of `numpy.float64` values or similar. (Might depend on the system, I guess.) Thus Python 2's integer-division-is-floor-division quirk doesn't come into play here.

Comment: With `xontest = vxon(2, t)` on Python 2.7.3 and NumPy 1.6.1, I'm getting `xontest == array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ,  1.2,  1.4,  1.6,
        1.8,  2. ,  2.2,  2.4,  2.6,  2.8,  3. ,  3.2,  3.4,  3.6,  3.8,
        4. ,  4.2,  4.4,  4.6,  4.8,  5. ,  5.2,  5.4,  5.6,  5.8,  6. ,
        6.2,  6.4,  6.6,  6.8,  7. ,  7.2,  7.4,  7.6,  7.8,  8. ,  8.2,
        8.4,  8.6,  8.8,  9. ,  9.2,  9.4])`, and thus a linear plot for t > 2.0.

Comment: das-g, actually, your answer was very helpful for me - I understood what to look at. As I just posted below, the problem was in `np.vectorize` in my case. When I added a "float" option to it, my code works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the problem. The line

```
vxon = np.vectorize(xon)
```

should be written as

```
vxon = np.vectorize(xon, otypes=[np.float])
```

Thank you, das-g, for showing me in which direction to dig.